# problems with di using castle windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am trying to learn di using windsor and am running into problems.  I have an existing DAL that I am using and I would like to use di with this dal.  I have the following interface (simplified for the sake of this post) -

```
public interface IConnection 
    {
        void OpenConnection(string ConnectionStringName);
        void CloseConnection();
        DbDataReader ExecuteReader(string query);
    }
```

and the implementation -

```
public class Connection : IConnection
    {
        private DBManager manager = new DBManager();

        public void OpenConnection(string ConnectionStringName)
        {
            manager.OpenConnection("connectionstringname");
        }

        public void CloseConnection()
        {
            manager.CloseConnection();
        }

        public DbDataReader ExecuteReader(string query)
        {
            return manager.ExecuteReader(query, CommandType.Text);
        }
    }
```

Here is my windsor installer -

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(
                Component.For<IConnection>().ImplementedBy<Connection>()
                .LifeStyle.Transient
                );
        }
```

and here is where I am doing the injection -

```
public class GetData
    {
        private IConnection conn;

        public GetData()
        {
        }

        public GetData(IConnection conn)
        {
            this.conn = conn;
        }

        public List<Entity> GetAllData()
        {
            List<Entity> data= new List<Entity>();
            //IConnection conn = new Connection();
            conn.OpenConnection("connectionstringname");

            try
            {
                var r = conn.ExecuteReader("select ... from ...");
                //code to convert reader to data list
                r.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.CloseConnection();
            }

            return data;            
        }
    }
```

the injection is not working.  If I step through the code, conn is always null in GetAllData.
when I step through at the installer, the IConnection/Connection dependency is there and it says that all required dependencies can be resolved.

Can anyone see anything that I am doing wrong?  As I said, I am new to di, so if I am using it incorrectly, please let me know.

thanks

**EDIT**
  - I'm not entirely sure I understand.  If I change my installer to the following, it still isn't working -

```
container.Register(
                Component.For<IConnection>().ImplementedBy<Connection>()
                .LifeStyle.Transient
                );

            container.Register(
                Component.For<GetData>()
                );

            container.Resolve<GetData>();
```

Am I way off base compared to what you said, or am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: where would I register GetData?

Comment: You need to register `GetData` in the container, then resolve it from the container. If you just do `new GetData()` the container can't inject anything.

Comment: Mauricio - thank you for the help but I still don't understand.  please see the edits above - am I moving in the right direction?

Comment: @czuroski: yes, that looks ok. Can you post a full testcase so I can exactly locate your problem?

Comment: @Mauricio - I do not have any test cases written....I haven't tried to write any yet as I wasn't sure how to handle them.

Comment: @czuroski: now would be a good time to do it ;-) You can post new questions if you have problems writing tests...

Comment: @Mauricio - yes - I was planning on getting some tests written, but I was trying first to understand how everything works together so that I can write the test effectively.  I will post a new question - thanks again.

Comment: @Mauricio - I have found that if I add the method call to the GetData - container.Resolve<GetData>().GetAllData(); - and I set my breakpoints in the GetAllData Method on the conn.OpenConnection() call, something strange happens.  When I run the application, it stops there and conn is populated correctly.  However, if I then run the application from the break, when the GetData method is actually called from the code conn is empty.  Does that give any insight?

Comment: I also found that if I move the injection to my controller, everything works properly.  I think I may just use the injection there and then change GetData().GetAllData() to accept my IConnection interface as a parameter.

Comment: @czuroski: to be honest, I don't like guesswork :) If you post a failing test I will take a look...

Comment: @Mauricio - I don't blame you.  I was able to get it working by moving the injection to my controller, so I think I will just stick with that.  Thank for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure and I might be wrong, but I didn't notice you call

```
container.Resolve
```

If you have worked with ASP.NET MVC, you can get this working automatically with [controller injection](http://blog4work.com/post/2011/02/24/Controller-injection-MVC-and-IoC.aspx), but you will still need to hook the interface to some kind of a factory method. In your sample I would add

```
public class GetData
{
    private IConnection conn = ContainerManager.Instance.Resolve<IConnection>();
    //where ContainerManager.Instance points to the container instance
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am using MVC and I have my controller injection working.  would it be best to call container.resolve where you said or in my WindsorControllerFactory?

Comment: @czuroski oh I see. I don't think you can use ASP.NET MVC injection for anything else but **Controller Injection**, so I think (might not be true), you cannot use it because ASP.NET has built-in factories that are hooked up automatically behind the scene. In my projects I create a base class that contains all the `Resolve` logic, and inherit types from this base.

Answer (score 0):

did you call install()? for instance:

```
container.Install(Castle.Windsor.Installer.Configuration.FromAppConfig());
```